# I ate pizza yesterday vs I ate a pizza yesterday

Tags: articles

What's the difference and which one is correct?:

> I ate pizza yesterday.
>
> I ate a pizza yesterday.

Comment: Generally we expect people to do a bit of research before asking questions, then provide details of their research and explain what specifically they don't understand. In this case, you could look at a site like this https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/determiners-and-quantifiers/indefinite-article-and to find out about the indifinite article and count/noncount nouns.

Answer (score 6):

Either may be correct—it depends on what you mean.

"I ate **a** pizza" means that you ate one pie, no more or less.

"I ate pizza" means that you ate some pizza, but the quantity is not specified.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your context, the first example is correct if you ate an unspecified amount of pizza yesterday however, if you ate only one pizza then both the first and the second example are correct options to use.

Comment: But the first option is still correct – even if you ate one and exactly one pizza. (I think you mean, “the second example is ***a*** correct option you could use.”)